# Stack trace of crash report does not include my code. What can I do?

Tags: android, crash

I received the below stack trace as a crash report in my developer console.
Is there something I can do about it?
I have no ides where to start looking for the problem.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2581)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
        at android.os.Handler.disp            atchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4803)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeN            ative(N            ative Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
        at dalvik.system.N            ativeStart.main(N            ative Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$ResolveListAdapter.handlePackagesChanged(ResolverActivity.java:419)
        at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onRestart(ResolverActivity.java:220)
        at android.app.Instrument            ation.callActivityOnRestart(Instrument            ation.java:1173)
        at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:5063)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5074)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2571)
        ... 10 more
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the code:

Unfortunately the user did not add a message on when the crash occurred.

```
public class MainActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        InAppHelper.init(); // uses Helper and Logger
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        setContentView(R.layout.preferences_layout);
        if (PreferenceHelper.isShowDialogOnStartup()) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.popup_title);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.popup_text);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.popup_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.create().show();
            PreferenceHelper.setShowDialogOnStartup(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        InAppHelper.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menuContactUs:
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                ...
                intent.setType("ext/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Email:"));
                break;
            case R.id.menuRate:
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName()));
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your code pls

Comment: @VM4 As you can see, `ResolverActivity` resides in the `com.android.internal` package. OP is not calling anything there himself, hence the question.